# Why isn't Selenium capturing my keystrokes?

Tags: firefox, testing, selenium

I'm trying out the recorder of the latest Selenium IDE Firefox extension on win32/ff3.

On one page, currently I have to hit Enter to go to the next page, but it's not on a submit button, it's captured manually.  This is not picked up by the recorder.  I know I can enter it manually myself after recording, but why isn't this part of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Selenium FAQ:

http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SIDE/FAQ

"Not every event will be recorded by Selenium IDE. Usually the ones that won't be recorded are those that involve complex HTML and/or AJAX. We hope to improve this over time, but there will always be situations where the IDE can't record everything because it has to balance recording too little with too much."

Comment: Huh...that's kind of too bad that an Enter keypress is somehow considered "complex HTML and/or AJAX."  Well, hopefully some day...

Comment: Well crap, my web app relies almost completely on the keyboard to do stuff.  I downloaded Selenium hoping to automate all this typing, only to find it is utterly worthless?!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a different browser? Does it happen the same in FF2, IE ?
Use the latest nightly version. I know that there are some problems with FF3.

Comment: I didn't, actually...this particular test I only needed to have work on ff3.  I'd be interested in results some day though, so at that point I'll try it out...